# In C - what does if(ptr->name & 0x10) mean

Tags: c

Newbie on C language. I understand pointers and hex format but I'm not sure what '& 0x10'  is doing. Could someone kindly explain it or advise me on topics to research and teach myself. Thank you.

```
if(ptr1->name & 0x10)
{
     prt2->indicator1  |= 0x80;      
}
```

Comment: Do you know about bitwise operators?

Comment: Is `prt2` a typo? This code does a bitwise or with `0x80` and `prt2->indicator1` as operands and stores the result in `prt2->indicator1`. I'm not sure how to be more concrete than that without knowing what `prt2->indicator1` is.

Comment: if `ptr1->name` has its 5th bit set (or "bit 4" from zero-based), set the 9th bit of `ptr2->indicator`.  Typically these will be "flags" that say something is or isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure what '& 0x10' is doing. Could someone kindly explain it or advise
>   me on topics to research and teach myself. Thank you.

`if(ptr1->name & 0x10)`

Is taking whatever the value of `ptr1->name` is and [bitwise-ANDing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) it with `0x10`.

If you understand hex, then you know that `0x10` is 16 in decimal, and presumably you know that 16 is 2^4 which means in binary this value is `0b10000`.

If the result of this operation is non-zero, then this tells us that the 4th bit of `ptr1->name` is set (bit numbering starts at 0, e.g 2^0 = 0x1), and will result in the execution of the line `prt2->indicator1  |= 0x80;`

Check out [bitwise operators in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators)